# Prove that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is bounded and closed?

Tags: real-analysis

We've working on an exercise for Analysis which is the following:

Consider the following subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$A:\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2\ | 4(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2\leq 25\}$$
Prove that the set $A$ is a closed and bounded subset of $(\mathbb{R}^2,||\cdot||_2)$.

We tried to show that the complement, $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash A$, is open, but we couldn't figure it out. Is it possible to do this with the complement or are we supposed to do it using a different method?

Comment: **Hint 1:** Take a convergent sequence of $A$ and show that it converges in $A$. **Hint 2:** If $f(x,y)=|4x^2+y^2|$, it's continuous and $A=f^{-1}((-\infty ,25])$.

Comment: Given a point not in A, can you center a circle of non zero radius there that is completely contained in A's complement? Any point you can do that with is an interior point of A's complement. A set is open if all its points are interior points. The complement of an open set is closed. Alternatively, a set is closed if it contains all its boundary points.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that the set $A$ is closed, I suggest combining the continuity of the function

$f(x_1,x_2)=4 x_1^2 + x_2^2$

with the fact that the interval $(-\infty,25]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.